# Github Pages with XHTML 1.0 Strict, Can I use without Cloudflare mail protection?

Tags: github, xhtml, github-pages, cloudflare, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have deployed my XHTML 1.0 Strict compliant webpage into Github Pages. However, an error occurred because of the Cloudflare mail protection. it was run automatically.

```
[Error] Line 204, Column 160: there is no attribute "data-cfemail"
...on" class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="4f3c3a3f3f203d3b0f2a373b3c61243d">[emai...

[Error] Line 206, Column 176: there is no attribute "data-cfemail"
...pan class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="97e4e2e7e7f8e5e3d7f2efe3e4b9fce5">[emai...

[Error] Line 236, Column 30: there is no attribute "data-cfasync"
...script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-...

[Error] Line 236, Column 107: required attribute "type" not specified
...cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script><script src="assets/js/jquery-...
```

Can I disable the Cloudflare mail protection in my Github Pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by creating a separate `.xhtml` file as example of `index.xhtml`. However, the `index.xhtml` does not guarantee the same behavior as `index.html`.